# Can you make an alert dialog take 100% of the width on screen?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-custom-view, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I am trying to make my alert dialog (not custom dialog), take up 100% of the width on screen from end to end ,but even if I set it to match parent width, it still takes up like 90% of the width with some gaps on left and right(also i m trying to set the gravity to bottom and still theres some space from bottom too) . not sure if I do need a custom dialog to do this or is there any way an alert dialog can take up the entire screen width without being custom? Any ideas?
Here's my code for reference:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getMyActivity());
     AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.getWindow().setLayout(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
            dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation; 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
            dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);


            wmlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM ;
            dialog.show();
```

Comment: can you please solve my problem i am trying to set custom view with alert dialog not  from the activity class and when i am trying to getWindow (dialog.getWindow) method with dialog its giving me an error and i want to set the dialog to 90% of the screen

Comment: Not sure about dialogs, but maybe you can use fragment with transparent background in the top and bottom edges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below code

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
```

or add custom theme in your style.xml

```
 <style name="DialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">

<item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
<!-- No backgrounds, titles or window float -->
<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
```

while inflating your dialogue set this theme

```
dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.DialogTheme);
```

Comment: replacing <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item> to <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item> did the trick! thanks!